# Handling Exception in LINQ query

Tags: c#, xml, exception

I have a XML file with a bunch of objects, which can have multiple fields, for example:

```
<object>
  <obj_name>Car</obj_name>
  <field>
    <name>Brand</name>
    <type>string</type>
    <value>Volvo</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>Power</name>
    <type>int</type>
    <value>200</value>
  </field>
</object>
```

I should read from the file only objects that have a name and at least one field. The field to be valid must have name, type (string or int) and value. I wrote this query:

```
var objects = from newobject in 
              XDocument.Load("input.xml").Descendants("object")
                     where (string)newobject.Element("obj_name") != ""
                     select new DataObject
                     {

                         Name = (string)newobject.Element("obj_name"),
                         Fields = new List<Field>(
                             from fields in newobject.Elements("field")
                             where (string)fields.Element("name") != ""
                             where (string)fields.Element("type") != "" && ((string)fields.Element("type") == "string" || (string)fields.Element("type") == "int")
                             where (string)fields.Element("value") != ""
                             select new Field
                             {
                                 Name = (string)fields.Element("name"),
                                 Type =  (string)fields.Element("type"),
                                 Value = (string)fields.Element("value")                                
                             })    
                     };
```

It works fine but the problem is the file can have also invalid tags, for example `<name>Bob</type>` which cause exceptions. How can I skip objects/fields with broken tags and handle the exceptions within this query?

Comment: You must fix errors before running c#.   The Net library XML classes will not allow any XML file to be read with matching tag errors.  You could read file using TEXT classes and then fix, but it is strongly recommended to fix these XML errors and not write kludge software to work around real issues.

Comment: I personally think if the xml is invalid, you should not read any data from it. I mean, _how_ do you want to "skip" the element. Is the `name` tag really "closed" after the `</type>` tag? What if a `>` is completly missing. I don't see a good way to parse broken xml reliably.

Comment: My task is to write a query that can handle mistakes like this so I can't fix this before reading.  One tag being closed by another is the only invalid data case, the file won't be missing `< ` or ` > '.

Comment: There are utilities that attempt to repair broken XML, for example XMLTidy. However, this is a bit like trying to repair broken Java or C# code (or indeed like a spelling corrector) - it might always produce something that's syntactically valid, but it won't always be what the writer intended. It's far better to fix the program that generated the bad XML to start with.

Comment: I get your point of view for sure, but it's a recruitment task and the xml file is given.